# REST api request method input parameters

Tags: api, rest, backbone.js, restful-architecture

i've been researching/creating a REST api, in the backbone.js to php context.

i understand the concept of HTTP verbs and when they should be used

`GET - select`

`POST - create`

`PUT - update`

`DELETE - delete`

i also understand the concept of passing an identifier as a semantic url, e.g.

`GET http://api/users/123`

`DELETE http://api/users/123`

in these cases the "123" is the id the business logic will use to get/delete a user.

but what about the POST and PUT contexts? when sending a request to

`PUT http://api/users/123`

the api will update user id 123 with the supplied parameters, here's where my question arises.

i would assume the input parameters to update with would be sent as PUT parameters. in php syntax this is represented as: `file_get_contents('php://input')` (this is the same for delete requests.)

when testing this via backbone.js it works perfectly.

but when i try and create a new element with

`POST http://api/users/`

i would assume the input values would sent as POST parameters/ in php syntax this is represented as `$_POST`. but this does not work.

after some testing, and reading up on rails style REST apis (which is what the backbone docs suggest), i realized that **all** request variables are sent the same way. if i change my code to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` to get the request parameters for every request type,  backbone works perfectly.

is this standard fair for REST apis? or just "rails flavored" ones?

Comment: I'd also like to know this. It doesn't seem to me that there's any real standard in RESTful style APIs with respect to the format of the request or response bodies, and a lot of what I've seen about building REST APIs basically just glosses over the issue. I typically write them with pure JSON in the request and response bodies, not form encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT, POST, PATCH, etc (everything but GET and DELETE*) accept request bodies. Generally data is passed as either:

- A URL encoded string of name/value pairs (exactly the same as a URL querystring) that is decoded and parsed by the server into `$_POST` (or similar depending on your web framework of choice). ***This typically relies on the presence of a `Content-Type` header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`*** (browsers do this by default when forms are submitted). If you see the data in `file_get_contents('php://input')` but not `$_POST` it's very likely this header is not present or is set to another value. If you're using Chrome, you can see what headers and body the client is sending in the Network tab of the dev tools.
- The other popular request body format is to use `Content-Type: application/json` and then write out a JSON string to the body. This can be accessed via `file_get_contents('php://input')` and then parsed with a JSON parser.

* Note on DELETE: [it's a little unclear whether or not using a request body with DELETE is allowed or a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request).

Comment: If the API calls are over public URLs, you can also use Runscope to inspect the requests/responses /shamless_plug

Comment: i like the idea of checking the presence of a Content-Type header set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. then either reading the request body or php input. thanx!